# Let $n=2m$, where $m$ is odd. How many elements of order $2$ does the group $D_n/Z(D_n)$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $n=2m$, where $m$ is odd. How many elements of order $2$ does the group $D_n/Z(D_n)$ have?

I don't how to begin this proof. All I have so far is that Dn/Z(Dn) should have one element of order 2.

Comment: The first thing you have to do is work out what $Z(D_n)$ is. Can you do that? Also, $D_n/Z(D_n)$ is not a subgroup, it's a quotient group.

Comment: would it be Z? just the integers

Comment: I think you misunderstand the notation. The integers are not involved. If $G$ is a group, $Z(G)$ is notation for the *center* of the group. So you need to know what $D_n$ means, and then you need to figure out what its center is.

Comment: I know Dn is the Dihedral group and for D4 the center is {Ro,R180} but im not sure what the center for Dn is. would it just be the Dihedral group without R0?

Comment: Huh? if by $R_0$ you mean the identity element of $D_n$, then that's always in the center. Do you know what "center" means in the context of group theory?

Comment: it means that the element is abelian with every other element in that group right? and i'm using R0 as the identity. I just don't understand what elements are in this factor group

Comment: The center of $G$ is the collection of elements of $G$, each of which commutes with every element of $G$. Now you have to figure out, if $n$ is twice an odd number, which elements of $D_n$ commute with every element of $D_n$. You can think about it geometrically: are there any rotations that commute with every flip? any flips that commute with every rotation? Or, you can go to generators and relations, if you know about that stuff: $D_n$ is the set of all elements of the form $a^ib^j$ with $0\le i\le n-1$, $0\le j\le1$, $a^n=1$, $b^2=1$, $ba=a^{-1}b$ and work out when two elements commute.

Comment: Hint :Notice that n = 2m where m is odd that implies $D_n$ has a sylow 2- subgroup.

Comment: I was never taught the concept of a sylow subgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: notice that n = 2m where m is odd that implies $D_n$ has a sylow 2- subgroup.
Now see that $D_n$ is a finite group and $Z(D_n)$ the center of $D_n$ is a subgroup of $D_n$ then what can you say about the order and index of these groups and subgroups, also use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Our teacher never taught us what a sylow subgroup is.  I honestly do not understand this problem or where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

SO I have that the Dn/Z(Dn)={R0,R180}. I also figured out that the order of Dn=(m+1)(n+1)=(mn)+2n+m+1. But I don't know where to go from here.